# How can I get rid of these artifacts in blender internal? They appear on mesh with subdivision-modifier and lamp with raytraced shadows

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, artifacts

When using a lamp with raytraced shadows active, artifacts appear in the shadows on the mesh IF the mesh has a subdivison modifier in the stack.

[image: artifacts in raytraced shadow on mesh with subdivision modifier]

But if I apply the modifier and re-render the artifacts disappear.

[image: no artifacts when subdivision modifier applied to mesh]

How can I achieve the same result without applying the subdivision modifier?